# ScrollView内にあるImageViewをタップした時の座標値を取得したい（Swift2.1）

Tags: ios, swift

UIScrollView内にUIImageViewを入れ，スクロール及びピンチによる拡大縮小が可能な状況で，
UIImageViewに表示した画像をタップするとその座標値を取得したいのですが，
unrecognized selector sent to instanceというエラーがコンソールに表示されて，うまくいきません．以下コードです．

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // scrollview settings
    self.myScrollView.delegate = self
    self.myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
    self.myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 8
    self.myScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    self.myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true

    let singleTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self
        , action:"singleTap:")
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)
}

// zoom
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.myImageView
}

// singleTap
func singleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer, touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Void {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        let pointX = point.x
        let pointY = point.y
        print(pointX)
        print(pointY)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

func singleTapの部分を以下のようにしていた時はエラーがなかったので，引数や戻り値の部分に問題があるのではないかと思っております．

```
func singleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    print("tapped")
}
```

様々なネット上のサンプルを見よう見まねで進めているため，全くおかしなコードを書いてしまっているかもしれませんが，教えていただけますと幸いです．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> func singleTapの部分を以下のようにしていた時はエラーがなかったので，引数や戻り値の部分に問題があるのではないかと思っております．

はい、そのとおりです。`UIGestureRecognizer`が送るアクションメソッドは、引数に`UIGestureRecognizer`インスタンス自身を持ち、引数の数はひとつだけです。

タッチした座標は、`UIGestureRecognizer`のメソッド`func locationInView(_ view: UIView?) -> CGPoint`あるいは`func locationOfTouch(_ touchIndex: Int, inView view: UIView?) -> CGPoint`で取得できますから、`UITouch`がなくてもかまいません。

```
// singleTap
func singleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    for i in 0..<gesture.numberOfTouches() {
        let point = gesture.locationOfTouch(i, inView: self.view)
        let pointX = point.x
        let pointY = point.y
        print(pointX)
        print(pointY)
    }
}
```